# org.hibernate.sessionexception session is closed

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate,and when I perform an update,it gives me this exception:-

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

2015-03-17 17:04:54,541 1412797 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-2:)   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:127)

2015-03-17 17:04:54,542 1412798 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-2:)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:753)

2015-03-17 17:04:54,544 1412800 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-2:)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)

2015-03-17 17:04:54,545 1412801 ERROR [stderr] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-2:)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
```

Below is my code

```
public void update(Rest rest){ 
    Setting settdao = new Setting();
    Transaction tr = null;   
try {
        Session session=getSession();
        tr = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(rest);
        settdao.addSub(rest,session);
        tr.commit();
        log.debug("update successful");
    } 
catch(Exception e)
    {
         e.printstacktrace();  
    }
```

Below addSub() method from the above update() method:-

```
private int addSub(Rest rest, Session session) {
try {
       session.save(rest);  //Here,I get the Hibernate exception.
    }

catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printstacktrace();  
    }
 return 1; 
}
```

Am I going wrong? What could be the reason. Please help.

Comment: I wonder how it compiles ... `return 1; ` is in between try catch !! Please place it in appropriate place !!

Comment: that was just typo,updated my code now,thanks Junaid.

Comment: So what does your `getSession` method does?

Comment: It returns the session object as follows:-   public Session getSession() {return HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();}